# How to Display Text from a Loop with Arrays

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, loops

So for an assignment, we have to insert coffee descriptions into an Array and loop those arrays so that they display somewhere else on our webpage. So far I have the descriptions in the Array and a non-working loop, so I am at a loss.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>The Coffee Shop</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>The Coffee Shop</h1>
<h2>Best coffee in Pennsylvania!</h2>

<form name="drinkList" method="get">
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        /* <![CDATA[ */
        /*
        Javascript code for "Order Form" tag
        */
        // 9/22/2015
        document.write("<p><strong>Order Form</strong>: ");

        var info = new Array(5)
        var drinkInfo = new Array(5)
        drinkInfo[0] = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans.";
        drinkInfo[1] = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream.";
        drinkInfo[2] = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)";
        drinkInfo[3] = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage.";
        drinkInfo[4] = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle.";

        var money = new Array(5)
        var price = new Array(5)
        price[0] = "$0.99";
        price[1] = "$3.29";
        price[2] = "$2.99";
        price[3] = "$3.99";
        price[4] = "$1.29";

        var coffees = document.getElementsByTagName("b");

        for (var i = 0; i < drinkInfo.length; i++) {
            coffees[i].innerHTML += " " + drinkInfo[i];
        }

        /* ]]> */


             </script> 
                    <!-- Below adds First name, Last name, Phone number, and Payment type. -->
                       <p> 
                           First Name:
                           <input type="text" name="firstName" />
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           Last Name:
                           <input type="text" name="lastName" />
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           Phone Number *(123)-456-7890*:
                           <input type="text" name="phoneNumber" />
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           Payment Type:
                           <select name="options">
                           <option>Choose One</option>
                           <option>Visa</option>
                           <option>Mastercard</option>
                           <option>Paypal</option>
                           </select>
                        <p> <!-- Textboxes for drinks -->
                            <strong>Enter quantity for your choice of drink:</strong>
                            <br />
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" name="quant1" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Black Coffee:</b>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" name="quant2" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Loco Mocha:</b>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" name="quant3" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Vanilla Bean Frappuccino:</b>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" name="quant4" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Pumpkin Spice Latte:</b>
                            <br />
                            <input type="text" name="quant5" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Caramel Macchiato:</b>
                            <br />
                        </p>
                           <!-- Adds extra choices -->
                           <strong>Select any extras:</strong>
                           <br />
                           <br />
                           <input type="text" name="whip" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> Whipped Cream
                           <br />
                           <input type="text" name="cream" value="0" style="width: 25px;"  /> Cream
                           <br />
                           <input type="text" name="sugar" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> Sugar
                           <br />
                           <input type="text" name="chocolate" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> Chocolate
                           <br />
                           <input type="text" name="caramel2" value="0" style="width: 25px;" /> Caramel
                           <br />
                           <br />

                           <!-- Submit button -->
                           <input type="submit" value="Order" />

                           <!-- Functional Reset button -->
                           <input type="reset" value="Reset" />
           </form>
<div id="footer" class="CR" align="center">
            &copy; All rights reserved. The Coffee Shop.
        </div>
```

The loop above is what some of you suggested, but isn't working. Idk why, but ya. It works in a new page, but not in the current. Probably because I have Prints everywhere, but that is how we were told to write the webpage.

Comment: Can you provide an example of the final expected HTML output pls

Comment: it should be `i++` inside for the for loop

Comment: drinkInfo[0] should appear to the immediate right of <b>Black Coffee:</b>

And so on.

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 are you allowed to give the `<b>` elements a class? or add any HTML to the current markup?

Comment: Currently you  have a for loop that concatenates the strings.  That doesn't help.  `displayInfo` needs to find the correct location to insert each piece of text into the (already existing ?) document, and perform the insertion.

Comment: @RajaKhoury Honestly I have no idea since it is a very basic level class, but I highly doubt the professor will care, as long as it is finished. Not sure if she wants us to follow our notes or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try one of the following:

Using original formatting:

```js
var info = new Array(5);
var drinkInfo = new Array(5);
drinkInfo[0] = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans.";
drinkInfo[1] = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream.";
drinkInfo[2] = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)";
drinkInfo[3] = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage.";
drinkInfo[4] = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle.";

// get all <b> tags
var coffees = document.getElementsByTagName("b");

// loop through all drinkInfos and append the info to the corresponding <b> element
for (var i = 0; i < drinkInfo.length; i++) {
  coffees[i].innerHTML += " " + drinkInfo[i];
}
```

```html
<strong>Enter quantity for your choice of drink:</strong> <br /><br />

<input type="text" name="quant1" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Black Coffee:</b> <br />
<input type="text" name="quant2" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Loco Mocha:</b>  <br />
<input type="text" name="quant3" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Vanilla Bean Frappuccino:</b>  <br />
<input type="text" name="quant4" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Pumpkin Spice Latte:</b>  <br />
<input type="text" name="quant5" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Caramel Macchiato:</b>  <br />
```

Using table for a better design:

```js
var coffees = [
    "Black Coffee",
    "Loco Mocha",
    "Vanilla Bean Frappuccino",
    "Pumpkin Spice Latte",
    "Caramel Macchiato",
];

var info = [
    "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans.",
    "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream.",
    "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)",
    "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage.",
    "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle.",
];

var table = document.createElement("table");

for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
    // create a row for each coffee
    var row = document.createElement("tr");
    // first cell contains the input element
    var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
    cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quant' + (i+1) + '" style="width: 25px" />';
    // second cell contains the coffee name
    var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
    cell2.innerHTML = "<b>" + coffees[i] + ":</b>";
    // third cell contains the coffee description
    var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
    cell3.innerHTML = info[i];
    // appending all cells to current row
    row.appendChild(cell1);
    row.appendChild(cell2);
    row.appendChild(cell3);
    // appending the row to the table
    table.appendChild(row);
}
// and finally, appending the table to the body
document.body.appendChild(table);
```

```html
<strong>Enter quantity for your choice of drink:</strong> <br /><br />
```

Also, you can create an object for each coffee and add name and info properties: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/4otgb6yL/)

If you're going to place your script in the head, you can wrap your code with `window.onload`:

```
window.onload = function() {
    // ...
    var table = document.createElement("table");

    for (var i = 0; i < coffees.length; i++) {
        // create a row for each coffee
        var row = document.createElement("tr");
        // first cell contains the input element
        var cell1 = document.createElement("td");
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" name="quant' + (i+1) + '" style="width: 25px" />';
        // second cell contains the coffee name
        var cell2 = document.createElement("td");
        cell2.innerHTML = "<b>" + coffees[i] + ":</b>";
        // third cell contains the coffee description
        var cell3 = document.createElement("td");
        cell3.innerHTML = info[i];
        // appending all cells to current row
        row.appendChild(cell1);
        row.appendChild(cell2);
        row.appendChild(cell3);
        // appending the row to the table
        table.appendChild(row);
    }
    // and finally, appending the table to the body
    document.body.appendChild(table);
};
```

Comment: Your answer is the best one

Comment: Where do I add the top code? Because when it is added in the head, nothing happens, and I can't place it anywhere else or it will print the code itself..

Comment: @akinuri I updated my main post to show you the code that I am working with. I think my problem is that I have everything surrounded with Prints.

Comment: @akinuri Actually I got it now. I tossed all of the Prints and added a script underneath the Payment Types. Now is there anyway I can get strong [title] before all of that, because now the entire thing migrated to the bottom of the page?

Comment: @RockGuitarist1 You can find your whole working code in here [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/vw85usrf/). Put your script tag at the end of the document, before the body closing tag.

Comment: Thank you. I was hoping I wouldn't have needed help, but after many hours of trying I would have never figured this out. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

You were on your way to getting to your solution. This should do it for you.

```
var info = new Array(5)
var drinkInfo = new Array(5);

drinkInfo[0] = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans.";
drinkInfo[1] = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream.";
drinkInfo[2] = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)";
drinkInfo[3] = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage.";
drinkInfo[4] = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle.";

function displayInfo() {
    var fullInfo = ""
    for (var i = 0; i < drinkInfo.length; ++i) {
        if (i === 0) {
            fullInfo += '<strong>Enter quantity for your choice of drink:</strong><br />';
        }

        fullInfo += '<input type="text" name="quant' + (i + 1) + '" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>' + drinkInfo[i] + '</b><br />';
    }
}
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jonsuh/q3sbx6bs/

Answer (score 0):

If drinkInfo[i] should be to the right of `</b>` then you should put your input after the `</b>`

Answer (score 0):

```js
  var info = new Array(5)
  var drinkInfo = new Array(5);

  drinkInfo[0] = "Plain black coffee brewed from our finest of roasted coffee beans.";
  drinkInfo[1] = "Chocolate mocha flavored, covered in chocolate chips and topped with whipped cream.";
  drinkInfo[2] = "Vanilla flavored iced drink, topped with whipped cream and caramel. (No coffee added)";
  drinkInfo[3] = "Pumpkin flavored latte, with espresso and milk mixed together for a delicious beverage.";
  drinkInfo[4] = "Steamed milk with vanilla-flavored syrup is marked with espresso and topped with caramel drizzle.";


  function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
  }

  function displayInfo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < drinkInfo.length; i++) {
      var form = document.forms[0]
      firstChild = form.childNodes[1];
      var text = document.createElement('span');
      text.innerHTML = drinkInfo[i];
      var n = "quant" + (i + 1);
      insertAfter(text, document.getElementsByName(n)[0].nextSibling.nextSibling);
    }
  }


  displayInfo();
```

```html
<form>
  <strong>Enter quantity for your choice of drink:</strong>
  <br/>
  <input type="text" name="quant1" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Black Coffee:</b>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="quant2" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Loco Mocha:</b>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="quant3" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Vanilla Bean Frappuccino:</b>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="quant4" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Pumpkin Spice Latte:</b>
  <br />
  <input type="text" name="quant5" style="width: 25px;" /> <b>Caramel Macchiato:</b>
  <br />
</form>
```